# Aligning objects in different tikzcd diagrams

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, tikz-cd

I am trying to put several tikzcd diagrams into a single figure* environment, and looking for a way to align these diagrams so that the n-th objects from each diagram are aligned precisely in a same vertical line.

To be specific, the following TEX code

```
\begin{figure*}[h]
$G: $
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=40,row sep=20, ampersand replacement=\&]
    \mathrm{U}(1) \rar["i"] \dar["i"] \& 
    \mathrm{U}(2) \rar \dar \& 
    \mathrm{U}(3) \rar \dar \& 
    \cdots \&
    \mathrm{Sp}(1) \dar \rar \& 
    \mathrm{Sp}(2) \dar \rar \& 
    \mathrm{Sp}(3) \rar \dar \&
    \cdots
    \\
    \mathrm{O}(2) \rar \& 
    \mathrm{O}(4) \rar \& 
    \mathrm{O}(6) \rar \& 
    \cdots \& 
    \mathrm{U}(2) \rar \& 
    \mathrm{U}(4) \rar \& 
    \mathrm{U}(6) \rar \& 
    \cdots
\end{tikzcd}
\par\vspace{10mm} 
$\pi_0: $
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=40,row sep=20, ampersand replacement=\&]
    0 \rar \dar \& 
    0 \rar \dar \& 
    0 \dar \rar \& 
    \cdots \& 
    0 \dar \rar \& 
    0 \dar \rar \& 
    0 \dar \rar \& 
    \cdots 
    \\
    \bb{Z}_{2} \rar \& 
    \bb{Z}_{2}\times \bb{Z}_{2} \rar \& 
    \bb{Z}_{2} \rar \& 
    \cdots \& 
    0 \rar \& 
    0 \rar \& 
    0 \rar \& 
    \cdots 
\end{tikzcd}
\caption{\textbf{diagram}}
\end{figure*}
```

produces something like
[image: two commutative diagrams]

Please note that I am using a shorthand notation "\bb" for "\mathbb":

```
\def\bb{\mathbb}
```

To make these look more neat, one could try adjusting the variable 'column sep' manually (the first one from 40 to 35, the second from 40 to 43) to get something like

[image: two commutative diagrams, manually aligned]

but certainly the positions of the objects from two diagrams match only on the leftmost and rightmost entries. Is there a way to align the diagrams more neatly, preferably in an automatic manner?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make one diagram.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\bb}{\mathbb}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=30,row sep=20]
    \mathrm{U}(1) \arrow[r,"i"] \arrow[d,"i","{\makebox[0pt][r]{$\textstyle G$:\quad}}"'] & 
    \mathrm{U}(2) \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & 
    \mathrm{U}(3) \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & 
    \cdots &[-2em]
    \mathrm{Sp}(1) \arrow[d] \arrow[r] & 
    \mathrm{Sp}(2) \arrow[d] \arrow[r] & 
    \mathrm{Sp}(3) \arrow[r] \arrow[d] &
    \cdots
    \\
    \mathrm{O}(2) \arrow[r] & 
    \mathrm{O}(4) \arrow[r] & 
    \mathrm{O}(6) \arrow[r] & 
    \cdots & 
    \mathrm{U}(2) \arrow[r] & 
    \mathrm{U}(4) \arrow[r] & 
    \mathrm{U}(6) \arrow[r] & 
    \cdots
\\
    0 \arrow[r] \arrow[d,"{\makebox[0pt][r]{$\textstyle \pi_0$:\quad}}"'] & 
    0 \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & 
    0 \arrow[d] \arrow[r] & 
    \cdots & 
    0 \arrow[d] \arrow[r] & 
    0 \arrow[d] \arrow[r] & 
    0 \arrow[d] \arrow[r] & 
    \cdots 
    \\
    \bb{Z}_{2} \arrow[r] & 
    \bb{Z}_{2}\times \bb{Z}_{2} \arrow[r] & 
    \bb{Z}_{2} \arrow[r] & 
    \cdots & 
    0 \arrow[r] & 
    0 \arrow[r] & 
    0 \arrow[r] & 
    \cdots 
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\caption{Diagram}

\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wasn't aware that I could attach a box to the arrows in such a way! That is likely to help my future work as well. Thank you so much for your help.